# Running a Sensu handler on the client instead of the server

Tags: sensu

I have the following problem: I am using sensu to monitor some raspberry pis. Im using standalone checks which works just fine. Now sometimes it might happen that one of the pis lost its wifi connection or just gets restarted manual and dhcp fails or for some other reason has no internet connection. The idea is to let the pi check it self for a internet connection and if the check fails it should solve the problem by it self like restarting wifi or reboot the pi. 
Of course a simple bash script with a cronjob should do the job but I want to do the check with sensu. The problem is obvious if the check fails i don't have a internet connection and therefore can't send the check result to the sensu server.
Long story short ;) is it possible to implement something like the remediation feature just on the client? So that a handler on the client it self starts the script which should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Standalone checks are scheduled by the client but the check result us still published to the server. The result is then handled by the handler which resides on the server.

You could write a standalone "check" plugin which monitors the wifi and  if it is off then it will turn it on. It isn't using a handler though.

Comment: I tried writing an extension handler and  run this handler on the client but this did not work. So I wrote the standalone "check" plugin like you mentioned and this works well. So thanks for your answer.